# Haskell: get all paths

Tags: haskell

I'm looking for a smart way to get all paths traversing a given data structure.
I figured out that I need a function like this:

```
allPaths :: (a -> [a]) -> a -> [[a]]
```

It takes a seed `a` and a function `a -> [a]` (from each "a", you can get to multiple a's). The result is a list of paths starting from the seed.

My definition is:

```
allPaths :: (a -> [a]) -> a -> [[a]]
allPaths f a = map (a:) (concatMap (allPaths f) (f a))
```

But it doesn't quite work:

```
ghci> let f a = if a == 1 then [2, 3] else if a == 2 then [4] else []
ghci> allPaths f 1
[]
```

The result should be: `[[1,2,4], [1,3]]`, representing all the possible paths starting from 1.

EDIT: I search this signature into Hoogle, it yelds two functions: https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=%28a+-%3E+%5Ba%5D%29+-%3E+a+-%3E+%5B%5Ba%5D%5D&scope=set%3Astackage
However, both are giving me the same result as mine.

Comment: What is a path traversing a data structure? Which data structure? A directed graph?

Comment: very nice! :) ____

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, Yes, you can think of a directed graph. This graph is contained in the argument function f, that will "query" the graph for a node, and give the list of target nodes.

Comment: Please provide definitions and give an example where the input is clearly specified. You mention what the result should be, but that is the output. Where is the input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to the other answer, if you want all paths, not just all paths that arrive at a dead-end, then you need to prepend `[]` to the solution at *each* step, not just the final one.

```
allPaths :: (a -> [a]) -> a -> [[a]]
allPaths f a = map (a:) ([] : concatMap (allPaths f) (f a))
```

On your proposed `f`, this gives

```
*Main> allPaths f 1
[[1],[1,2],[1,2,4],[1,3]]
```

It includes the two paths leading to a dead end, as your example does, but it also includes `[1]` and `[1,2]`, which are valid paths (they just aren't valid *maximal* paths). In particular, if your graph has cycles in it, then this approach will produce a valid infinite list of paths, whereas the other proposed answer will fail to produce any results as soon as it hits the cycle.

Comment: Thanks, it works. `ghci> let f a = if a == 1 then [2, 3] else if a == 2 then [1] else []; take 6 $ allPaths f 1` 
`ghci> [[1],[1,2],[1,2,1],[1,2,1,2],[1,2,1,2,1],[1,2,1,2,1,2]` However, it nose-dive directly into the loop. Is there a way to make a "breadth first search"? That is, to explore the branch [1, 3] before the loop?

Comment: @cdupont you could achieve breadth-first by maintaining that the result lists are always sorted by length, and then instead of concat-ing the subresults for different directions, you merge them together like in a merge sort.

Comment: @leftaroundabout the breadth-first version if not very clear to me. It seems that I need to use a queue, right? Like in this library: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fgl-5.4.2.4/docs/src/Data-Graph-Inductive-Query-BFS.html#bfsWith

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that as soon as you arrive at a `[]`, you never prepend anything to that because there are no endpoints to walk towards.

Instead, `[]` should indicate that this *is* an endpoint.

```
allPaths f a = case f a of
  [] -> [[a]]
  fa -> map (a:) $ concatMap (allPaths f) fa
```

Comment: Wow, I see. Thanks!